# format date from C# web method to java android?

Tags: java, c#, android

I have a C# Web API that return a date with format like this

```
"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1468595175500-0000)\/"
```

My android application got it, but it's a String type. So how can I convert it to Date object in android?

Answer (score 0):

The first part (before the - character) looks like a timestamp. 
By testing it as a timestamp, I get the date Fri Jul 15 17:06:15 CEST 2016
So I advise to check exactly the format and what represent the part after the - character in order to handle it in a convenient way.

Otherwise, for the first part, you can use a regex to capture the timestamp and create a java Date like that :

```
       Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("Date\\((\\d+)\\-");
       Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(data);
       boolean find = matcher.find();
       String timestamp = matcher.group(1);      
       Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```